# How to replace objects of a specific type anywhere in a JavaScript object with a custom string when serializing

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have a set of JavaScript objects similar to this:

```
let query:any = [
  {$match:{taskId: new ObjectId("62f0efaf451f8c1f678a29e9")}},
  {$match:{$or:[{fieldName1:new Date()}, {fieldName2:new Date("2022-08-08T11:12:47.198Z")}]}}
]
```

Note: field names, and query structure are variable and may consist of different nested combinations of objects and arrays

I need to stringify this, replacing Date objects and mongoDB ObjectId objects with custom strings.
I tried using a replacer function with JSON.stringify

Given below is the code only to replace date objects:

```js
    var query = [
      {$match:{$or:[{fieldName1:new Date()}, {fieldName2:new Date("2022-08-08T11:12:47.198Z")}]}}
    ]

    function customBodyEncoder(key, value) {
      console.log("value:", value)
      console.log("type: ", typeof(value))
      console.log("-------------------")
      if (value instanceof Date) {
        return `#new_date_${String(value)}`
      }
      return value
    }

    let queryString = JSON.stringify(query, customBodyEncoder)
    console.log(queryString)
```

Output string: *[{"$match":{"taskId":"62f0efaf451f8c1f678a29e9"}},{"$match":{"$or":[{"fieldName1":"2022-08-16T18:23:00.014Z"},{"fieldName2":"2022-08-08T11:12:47.198Z"}]}}]*

I need match elements by type and replace. However, it seems replacer gets elements already converted to string.

I need to get the output:

*[{"$match":{"taskId":"62f0efaf451f8c1f678a29e9"}},{"$match":{"$or":[{"fieldName1":"**#new_date_2022-08-16T18:10:15.015Z**"},{"fieldName2":"**#new_date_2022-08-08T11:12:47.198Z**"}]}}]*

Is there a way to replace elements anywhere in a JavaScript object with a custom string matching by it's **type** when serializing?

Edit:
My requirement was to preserve (encode and decode) date objects and mongoDB ObjectIds when serializing a JS object.
I was able to achieve it by using EJSON (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejson)

Comment: You can (ab)use the fact that `JSON.stringify` will call the `toJSON` method of a value if it exists to get the JSON representation. For example, dates already have a `toJSON` method that returns the ISO 8601 date format of the date.

Comment: That works, however I did not need to globally modify the toJSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your own implementation of JSON.stringify and check for type Date there. Here's an old implementation but should work for your case and it's easy to adapt.

```js
var query = [{
  $match: {
    $or: [{
      fieldName1: new Date()
    }, {
      fieldName2: new Date("2022-08-08T11:12:47.198Z")
    }]
  }
}]

console.log(myStringify(query))

function myStringify(value, only_standard_json) {
  // adapted from json.org
  var i, k, v, length, partial


  function quote(str) {
    var escapable =
      /[\\\"\x00-\x1f\x7f-\x9f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g,
      m = {
        '\b': '\\b',
        '\t': '\\t',
        '\n': '\\n',
        '\f': '\\f',
        '\r': '\\r',
        '"': '\\"',
        '\\': '\\\\'
      }
    return escapable.test(str) ?
      '"' + str.replace(escapable, function(a) {
        var c = m[a];
        return typeof c === 'string' ? c :
          '\\u' + ('0000' + a.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
      }) + '"' :
      '"' + str + '"';
  }
  switch (typeof value) {
    case 'string':
      return quote(value);
    case 'number':
      return isFinite(value) ? String(value) : 'null';
    case 'function':
      if (only_standard_json) {
        return null;
      }
      return "" + value;
    case 'boolean':
    case 'null':
      return String(value);
    case 'object':
      if (!value) {
        return 'null';
      }
      if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Date]') {
        return `#new_date_${String(value)}`
      }
      partial = [];
      if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {
        length = value.length;
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          partial[i] = myStringify(value[i], only_standard_json) || 'null';
        }
        return (partial.length === 0 ? '[]' : '[' +
          partial.join(',') + ']');
      } else {
        // object
        for (k in value) {
          if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
            v = myStringify(value[k]);
            if (v) {
              partial.push(quote(k) + ':' + v);
            }
          }
        }
        return (partial.length === 0 ? '{}' : '{' +
          partial.join(',') + '}');
      }
    default: // end case//
      throw new ErrorException("illegal type")
  }
}
```